# Retention Time Change in Reversed Phase Chromatography (revised)

Tags: chromatography, polarity

I previously learned in books that in reversed phase chromatography, retention time changes depending on the content in mobile phase, which means as the polarity of mobile phase increases, retention time decreases. For example, let's say there are two kinds of combination of water and methanol(5:5 and 6:4 ratio). The latter one's polarity is stronger. So, if we run an experiment with the latter one, retention time decreases than the former one. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: Please clarify "content of "what" in the mobile phase"? I can provide some explanation but clarify your question with a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking just the opposite. RPLC is usually done for hydrophobic compounds. C18 columns do not retain hydrophilic compounds; say uracil or cytosine will not show much retention.

Suppose you have a hydrophobic compound such as naphthalene and do RPLC using 50:50 Water: Methanol and 60:40 Water: Methanol. Which mobile phase would show higher retention for naphthalene? It will be 60:40 Water: Methanol system? Guess why? C18 column consists of long C-18 alkyl chains. What would naphthalene prefer? A highly hydrophobic C-18 alkyl chain or a water-rich mobile phase?

This is the typical surface chemistry of a RPLC column. Hydrophobic compounds prefer to stay sticking to the stationary phase. We need a higher methanol or acetonitrile concentration to elute them. Adding more water to the mobile phase *increases* the retention time.

[image]